# Tag Proposal 'minhag-theory'

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

Just as we have separate tags for halakha and minhag, I propose a separate tag for minhag-theory parallel to halakha-theory.

This would be for "questions about theoretical and general concepts of minhag".

---

I was inspired by this question: [Allowed to change Tefillin minhag?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77047/allowed-to-change-tefillin-minhag) which doesn't merely address a particular minhag, but rather addresses the larger issue of when minhag can be changed.

NOTE: one can suggest that the tag is appropriate, even if one thinks that the aforementioned question doesn't warrant it.

Comment: I propose that [tag:minhag] should fulfill this purpose. I don't really think the tag [tag:minhag] on a question about a particular minhag is particularly helpful.